# returning null or object in Linq-to-SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I'm looking for a record that is mapped to an object model, I have something like this:

```
var Output = (from x in MyDC.SomeTable
              where  ....
              select new SomeObjectModel()
              {
                 SomeProp = x.SomeColumnField

              }.Single();
```

Now, I want to return on object but only if the object was found I'm doing this:

```
var Output = (from x in MyDC.SomeTable
              where ....
              orderby x.SomeTime descending
              select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

This tells me if the object was found and from there, I want to be able to retrieve `SomeObjectModel()` and fill in its properties but only if there's an element that was found with the .`FirstOrDefault()` statement and combine all this into one query. I tried adding a `Select` after `.FirstOrDefault()` but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please; what happens? This *should* just be a cause of replacing `Single` with `FirstOrDefault`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` with your first version. You can also use `SingleOrDefault` if you are expecting only a single item or null.

```
var Output = (from x in MyDC.SomeTable
              where  ....
              select new SomeObjectModel()
              {
                 SomeProp = x.SomeColumnField

              }.SingleOrDefault(); //if only single item is expected or null

return Output;
```

Comment: In the query, I'm sorting all the returns of the where clause and I'm sorting them by descending to take the top one. If I add the orderby statement after the where clause, is this going to return the object based on the latest record in the DB?

Comment: `OrderBy` would return the items in ascending order, if you are trying to get latest records then I believe you need `OrderByDescending` on some `DateTime` type field.

Comment: I have orderby x.SomeDateTime descending

Comment: @frenchie, that should work, but are you expecting single or multiple records against your condition in `where` clause, if you are expecting `single` then use `SingleOrDefault`, if you are expecting multiple and want to get the first one then use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Thanks, caught that: changed it to FirstOrDefault!

Answer (score 1):

```
var OutputAsModel = (from x in MyDC.SomeTable
where ....
orderby x.SomeTime descending
select s).Select(o=>new SomeObjectModel(o)).FirstOrDefault();
```